# JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss6.x

```
List results= sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from org.gencat.gimah.dao.GimahCobramentTargeta ct where ct.expEcon.id=: idEE and ct.cobrament is null ")
                    .setParameter("idEE", idEE)
                    .list();

JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component Expedients for method public abstract java.util.List org.gencat.gimah.model.Expedients.doBuscarDetallExpeconAPartirGestio(long,java.lang.String,boolean) throws org.gencat.gimah.exception.GimahExcepcio,java.rmi.RemoteException: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not locate named parameter [idEE]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the parameter `ct.expEcon.id=: idEE`. It is incorrect to put a space after `:`. You need to use parameters by this way

`ct.expEcon.id = :idEE`

And, please, use more reasonable parameter's names. `idEE` is a bad choice, because of two neighbour capital letters  `E`.